# Equivalence of Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines

Consider the following two arguments

> "*For every non deterministic TM M1 there exists an **equivalent**
>   deterministic machine M2 recognizing the same language.*"
>   "***Equivalence*** of two Turing Machines is undecidable"

These two arguments seem a bit contradicting to me.
What should I conclude from these two arguments?

Comment: Not relevant, but... the first statement looks trivial. You probably want "non deterministic TM M1" there (?)

Comment: Not actually, my doubt was regarding the term "equivalence", based on the two theorems. So "deterministic TM M1" was supposed to be there. :)

Comment: As I said, my comment is indeed not relevant to your question, but the first statement still looks trivial, since taking M2=M1 proves it. It's not a statement you will find in a computability book, for instance.

Comment: Omg I made a blunder here!M1 was supposed to be Non-deterministic.Thanks a lot for your concern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These arguments are not really related, on several levels.

The first is that *existence* and *computability* are not the same thing. That is, even if there exists some object (e.g. a TM), it does not mean that *finding* (or computing) such an object can be done using a TM.

However, there is a more basic difference between the two statements. The first says that for every TM $M_1$, there exists some equivalent machine $M_2$. The second statement is that deciding, given $M_1$ and $M_2$, whether these two specific machines are equivalent, is undecidable.

Just to emphasize the difference, consider the following problem: given a TM $M_1$, is there some TM $M_2$, that is different from $M_1$, which is equivalent to $M_1$? This problem is trivial - the answer is always "yes" (e.g. just add a redundant state to $M_1$).

Answer (score 3):

"Equivalence is undecidable" means there is no *algorithm* (always halts after a finite time and correctly answers yes/no), "there is an equivalent" is just existence. I.e., given $M_1$ and $M_2$, no algorithm can tell if they are equivalent *for all cases of $M_1$ and $M_2$* (some cases can be answered simply, but not all). The other is that for $M_1$ there is an equivalent $M_2$. It is even easy to construct some, just shuffle the states around, or add a completely useless state.

Comment: However, in this case the existence is actually algorithmic – given a non-deterministic TM, we can construct algorithmically an equivalent deterministic TM.

Answer (score 0):

Argument 1 says that for every non-deterministic Turing machine, we can build a deterministic Turing machine for recognizing the same language.

Argument 2 is not related to argument 1.

Argument 2 says that even though there may be two Turing machines that are equal, can not decide or prove they are equal. so it is undecidable.